# Expand/collapse group nodes in ExpandableListView based on passed Cursor values?

Tags: android

I've got a ExpandableListView widget that is populated using an adapter based on the SimpleCursorTreeAdapter as shown below. I I query my SQL database for the ListView's group titles as well as a boolean value to whether the group should be expanded or collapsed (which is returned in a Cursor). I then feed this Cursor to my adapter and the list is populated and displayed.

The only thing I can't do, is have the group nodes in the ListView be expanded or collapsed based on the boolean value in the supplied Cursor. I want to have this happen when the activity containing this ExpandableListView widget is initally created, loaded, and displayed.

Is there a way to have my adapter take the boolean values supplied in the Cursor object and use them to expand or collapse these group nodes?

```
public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter
    {
        public MyExpandableListAdapter (Cursor cursor, Context context, int groupLayout, 
                                        int childLayout,
                                String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo,
                                       String[]childrenFrom,int[]childrenTo)
        {               
           super(context,cursor,groupLayout,groupFrom,groupTo,childLayout,childrenFrom,childrenTo);
        }

    @Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) 
    {
        String strCategory = 
                   groupCursor.getString(groupCursor.getColumnIndex("strCategory")); 

        Cursor cur = mainActivity.mDbHelper.getCardTitlesForCategory(strCategory);

        return cur;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your suggestions and advice.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611927/simplecursortreeadapter-and-cursorloader

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way!
I had the same problem and I used this code in my Activity:

```
private void expandGroups() {
    // ExpandableListView scheduleListView
    int itemsCount = this.scheduleListView.getCount();
    if(itemsCount > 0) {
        long timeNowSec = (new Date()).getTime()/1000 - ONE_DAY_SEC;
        Cursor cursor = null;
        SimpleCursorTreeAdapter adapter = (SimpleCursorTreeAdapter)this.scheduleListView.getExpandableListAdapter();
        for(int i=0; i<itemsCount; i++) {
            cursor = adapter.getGroup(i);
            long dateSec = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbDefinitions.TABLE_PAIRS.FIELD_DATE));
            if(dateSec > timeNowSec) {
                this.scheduleListView.expandGroup(i);
            }
            else {
                this.scheduleListView.collapseGroup(i);
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

In this code I expand all groups where date older then current date.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (place code to your activity onResume() or another useful place). After ExpandableListView and adapter are initialized, you can expand group nodes depending by cursor values:

```
    Cursor groupCursor = your_adapter.getCursor();        
    if( groupCursor.getCount() > 0 && groupCursor.moveToFirst() ) {
        do {
            boolean isExpanded = groupCursor.getInt( ....) > 0;
            if( isExpanded ) {
                your_list_view.expandGroup( groupCursor.getPosition() );
            }
        } while( groupCursor.moveToNext() );
    }
```